# Is Planck's constant a mathematical or a physical constant?

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, constants

Planck's constant $h$ came out of his considerations of black body radiation and features prominently in quantum physics. Recently I came across the statement that $-i\hbar = pq - qp$ for  elements $p$ and $q$ of a rather general non-commutative ring, but I it was not quite clear how "general".

Now I wonder: is the numerical value of $\hbar$ more something like $\pi$ or Euler's constant $e$, which come out of "pure math" (I now this is a bit fuzzy) or is it more like the speed of light, $c$, which can change its numerical value depending on which fundamental units one is working with?

If $\hbar$ can be derived in non-commutative algebra without relying on physics input, I would be grateful to get a link to a derivation.

Comment: As far as I know, it is a physical constant

Comment: I think the equation you're thinking of is to be understood as "the analogous form of $-i \hbar$ for non-commutative rings in this class is the commutator". Then in quantum mechanics we have a non-commutative ring of operators corresponding to measurable quantities, where this identification is exact.

Comment: The specific value of $\hbar$ is definitely physical, which shouldn't be shocking since it has physical units.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonably question and should not be getting downvotes. Presumably, there are systems of "natural" units where $\hbar$ does not equal $1$, and its value according to such systems could imaginably be a fundamental constant of mathematics. (It probably isn't. But the OP made the right call; namely, to ask.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Thanks, if this were an answer I would accept this one, since I think the existence of a physical unit is probably the best hint that it is a physical and not a mathematical constant.

Comment: Glad you thought it was useful, though I'd say Henning's answer below does a great job elaborating on the point I was making.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Planck's constant is a dimensionful quantity; its numerical value depends on which units you measure it in. Since the units are more or less arbitrary conventions, the precise numerical value is of no particular mathematical significance, nor does it have deep physical importance.

In particular, one of the arbitrary unit choices that go into determining the value of Planck's constant in SI units is the kilogram, which is still defined as the mass of one concrete physical object stored at the BIPM. If the kilogram definition is revised to be a matter of objective physical phenomena, it is conceivable that the value of Planck's constant would *in theory* be a deductive consequence of a sufficiently powerful Theory Of Everything. However, all the currently proposed such theories still seem to involve aribtrary constants, some of which are dimensionless.

One can choose to work in *natural units* which corresponds to defining that Planck's constant and a bunch of other physical constants considered fundamental, have nice exact numerical values such as $1$ or $2\pi$. However, that is still just a convention, and the particular value the constants take in such natural units is a product of the unit choice rather than a separately meaningful mathematical thing.

Comment: I think that saying the particular numerical value is not "of any physical importance" isn't _quite_ right, though only for anthropic reasons: $\hbar$ being small in SI units reflects the fact that meters/kilograms/seconds were chosen by human beings doing macroscopic experiments. The fact that those experiments could be done in ignorance of QM indicates that $\hbar$ had better be small when expressed in these units. Conversely, if one uses Planck units then $\hbar$ will be one but anything macroscopic will involve huge numbers.

Comment: @Semiclassical: You're right, that was a tiny bit stretched. I've tried to tone it down a bit.

Comment: I think that also in the maths (deformation quantization) one often hopes to be able to assume $\hbar$ is sufficiently small. Given a power series in $\hbar$, one is looking for a convergent one and the radius of convergence is not agnostic to the size of $\hbar$ (e.g. a given series might converge for $\hbar < 1$, but not for $\hbar = 1$).

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $h$ has a value only in a specified set of units. Since the units used are always arbitrary (the second and meter have no fundamental significance), there can be no special meaning of this constant in whatever units are chosen.